# kexec from within initramfs

Tags: busybox, initramfs

Can `kexec` be used from within `initramfs` to load up a new image and kernel?

It seems that `kexec` calls `shutdown` which then looks for `/dev/initctl`, which is missing from a `busybox` `initramfs` image.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `kexec` man page:

```
-e (--exec)
      Run the currently loaded kernel. Note that it will  reboot  into
      the loaded kernel without calling shutdown(8).
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that -- thanks!

Comment: @psusi Does busybox have kexec support? How did you add kexec to busybox?